# How to make a text value to column in excel downloaded from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to make a text value to column in excel downloaded from gridview
This is my grid view design code.
and binding code is in backend side.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridCustomer" runat="server" 
                onrowdatabound="gridCustomer_RowDataBound" >
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="FrozenHeader" />

                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                        <ItemTemplate>                                                              
    <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>                                                
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle />     
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="Account-No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserId")%>' CommandName="VIEW"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="Card No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mobno" HeaderText="Mobile" />

                    <asp:BoundField  DataField="TotalAmount_Tax" HeaderText="Balance(Inc.Tax)" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PyingAmount" HeaderText="Last Paid Amount"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPaidDate" HeaderText="Last Paid Date"  />


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedDtae" HeaderText="Last Updated Date" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="areaname" HeaderText="Area" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="subarea" HeaderText="Sub Area" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BoxTypeName" HeaderText="Box Type Name"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SnNo" HeaderText="STB No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ChipOrMACId" HeaderText="SIM/MAC No"  />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PackagePeriod" HeaderText="Package-Period" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PackageName" HeaderText="Package-Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivationDate" HeaderText="Activation-Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountExpiry" HeaderText="Account-Expiry" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Attending User" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="AadharCard" HeaderText="Aadhar Card" />
                                          <asp:BoundField DataField="NodeName" HeaderText="Node Name" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Created-Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Name" HeaderText="Connection Status" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And this below code is exporting to excel from gridview code
This methode i am calling on download click event.

```
Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Charset = "";
                string FileName = "CustomerData" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
                StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
                gridCustomer.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
                gridCustomer.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                gridCustomer.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
                Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
                Response.End();
```

so how to make a text coloumn in downloaded excel?

Comment: refer my code and use as you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code all of them inlcuding colors and center headers it would be use full to you....

```
  Gridview1.AllowPaging = false;
        ///serch(); or/// bind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;



        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Daybook.xls"));
        // Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.ContentType = "File/Data.xls";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Gridview1.RenderControl(htw);


        string cell = Gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count.ToString();

        //string headerTable30 = " " + " " + " " + " " + "City  ";
        //string strr30 = headerTable30.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        //string Head30 = "<b style='color: Blue'>" + strr30 + "</b>";

        string headerTable31 = " " + clntname.Text + " ";
        string strr31 = headerTable31.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head31 = "<table align=center><tr><td colspan=" + cell + " style='text-align:center; color: #177FC5;'><h3> " + headerTable31 + "</h3></td></tr></table>";

        string headerTable32 = " " + " Address ";
        string strr32 = headerTable32.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head32 = "<b style='color: Blue'>" + strr32 + "</b>";

        string headerTable33 = " " + add1.Text + " ";
        string strr33 = headerTable33.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head33 = "<b>" + strr33 + "</b>";

        string headerTable34 = " " + add2.Text + " ";
        string strr34 = headerTable34.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head34 = "<b>" + strr34 + "</b>";

        string headerTable35 = " " + add3.Text + " ";
        string strr35 = headerTable35.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head35 = "<b>" + strr35 + "</b>";

        string headerTable36 = " " + " City ";
        string strr36 = headerTable36.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head36 = "<b style='color: Blue'>" + strr36 + "</b>";

        string headerTable37 = " " + city.Text + " ";
        string strr37 = headerTable37.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head37 = "<b>" + strr37 + "</b>";

        string headerTable38 = " " + " Pincode ";
        string strr38 = headerTable38.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head38 = "<b style='color: Blue'>" + strr38 + "</b>";

        string headerTable39 = " " + pincode.Text + " ";
        string strr39 = headerTable39.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

        string Head39 = "<b>" + strr39 + "</b>";

        string Head40 = "<table><tr><td colspan=15><b>" + Head32 + "</b><b>" + Head33 + "</b><b>" + Head34 + "</b><b>" + Head35 + "</b></td></tr></table>";

        string Head41 = "<table><tr><td colspan=15><b>" + Head36 + "</b><b>" + Head37 + "</b><b>" + Head38 + "</b><b>" + Head39 + "</b></td></tr></table>";

        // string Head42 = "<table><tr><td colspan=15><b>" + Head35 + "</b><b>" + Head36 + "</b><b>" + Head37 + "</b><b>" + Head38 + "</b></td></tr></table>";

        string headerTable1 = "Day Book";
        string Head1 = "<table align=center><tr><td colspan=" + cell + " style='text-align:center; color: Red;'><h3> " + headerTable1 + "</h3></td></tr></table>";



        string headerTable8 = " " + " " + " " + " From";
        string strr8 = headerTable8.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        string Head8 = "<b style='color: Blue; '>" + strr8 + "</b>";

        string headerTable9 = " " + "  " + txtfrom.Text + " ";
        string strr9 = headerTable9.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        string Head9 = "<b>" + strr9 + "</b>";

        string headerTable10 = " " + " " + " " + " To";
        string strr10 = headerTable10.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        string Head10 = "<b style='color: Blue'>" + strr10 + "</b>";

        string headerTable11 = " " + " " + txtto.Text + "";
        string strr11 = headerTable11.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        string Head11 = "<b>" + strr11 + "</b>";

        string headerTable12 = " " + Label1.Text+" "+" "+Label2.Text;
        string strr12 = headerTable12.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        string Head12 = "<b>" + strr12 + "</b>";

        //string Head20 = "<table><tr><td colspan=15><b>" + Head2 + "</b><b>" + Head3 + "</b><b>" + Head4 + "</b><b>" + Head5 + "</b><b>" + Head6 + "</b><b>" + Head7 + "</b></td></tr></table>";
        string Head21 = "<table><tr><td colspan=10><b>" + Head8 + "</b><b>" + Head9 + "</b><b>" + Head10 + "</b><b>" + Head11 + "</b></td></tr></table>";
        string Head22 = "<table><tr><td colspan=10><b>" + Head12 + "</b></td></tr></table>";

        Response.Write(Head31);
        Response.Write(Head40);
        Response.Write(Head41);
        Response.Write(Head1);
        //Response.Write(Head20);
        Response.Write(Head21);
        Response.Write(Head22);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

use this also

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```